# Multiple condition query SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've tried to execute this code in SQLAlchemy with many difference approach but none of them work. Can someone help me out

```
SELECT * 
       FROM news_nlp_sentences 
       WHERE sentence_id IN (SELECT MAX(sentence_id) 
       FROM news_nlp_sentences 
WHERE "date_created" BETWEEN '2012-12-28' AND '2012-12-31' 
       AND "domain" = 'marketing_features' 
       GROUP BY sentence);
```

I 've tried

```
page = ConditionalSearch.query.filter(ConditionalSearch.sentence_id.in_(func.max(ConditionalSearch.sentence_id)), ConditionalSearch.domain == domain, ConditionalSearch.date_created>=from_date, ConditionalSearch.date_created<=to_date)
```

and I've even tried

```
sql_str = "SELECT * FROM news_nlp_sentences WHERE sentence_id in (SELECT MAX(sentence_id) FROM news_nlp_sentences WHERE date_created BETWEEN {} AND {} AND {} = {} GROUP BY sentence);".format(str(from_date), str(to_date), str(column_name), str(key_word)) The sql_str give me error about BETWEEN
```

Expected to get column with distinct sentences since there are some same sentences with difference `word_id` in the db. It works fine if I don't try to get the `MAX(sentence_id)` but I don't want to have the same sentence over and over again

Comment: Recommend you assign to a `query` variable, and then `print(query)` to see how the generated SQL differs from the (correct) SQL you posted in your question.

Comment: Please update your question with the example code _and_ include the relevant stacktraces.